# Is Blender a mess for precise prototyping?

Tags: units, measurement

I came across this youtuber's video: "Sì .. VFX è così facile (tutorial Blender)"
that translates about "yes, VFX is so easy! (Blender Tutorial)"

I started with some Udemy courses, but I immediately noticed the measures didn't make any sense to me.

I mean, I can accept that the most advanced features would present some challenges, but the easy parts (create a circle in the middle of a cube) should be straightforward.

And after 2 days of scraping Google for the reason of my totally messed up Blender, here I am asking this experts community for a guide!

The Problem:

- I set Length to cm
- I set Unit Scale 0.01
- I create a new cube 2cm wide
- I get a cube with dimensions 0,000672cm?

[image: Blender sizes totally messed up]

What I tried:

- "Scene properties": changing the length to mm, m...
- "Scene properties": changing the scale...
- Item, dimensions: setting the dimensions to the right size (2cm for me), but I get a scale of 2977.1 in the Item "Scale"

If I won't be able to create exactly sized object, I'll have to think Blender is just for making animations, where it's more important to create a cute face, rather than be precise, so what free (or almost, up to 200€ TOTAL fee) software would you suggest? I need to quickly and exactly prototype small objects (phone holder, a camera prototype etc)

Comment: No, Blender is not less precise than most 3D programs. In any case, I can't reproduce this behavior. If I do it exactly as you describe, my cube has exactly 2cm. Do you have any more information?

Comment: I've justed tested this and based on the steps you've provided, I was unable to reproduce the problem. The dimension display correctly as 2 cm for me. Could you please make sure that you have not unintentionally modified the preferences in some way? Use *File > Defaults > Load Factory Settings* and then try again.

Comment: Looks like you're using the "Interactive Add" tool. Did you try to use the add menu instead ? Add/Mesh/Cube

Comment: As @thibsert says, you are using the _Add Cube interactively_ tool. This means the size entered there is not really relevant, this tool is made to add interactively by dragging the mouse for the size, only the keys Ctrl (for snapping), Alt (dragging from center) and Shift (fixing aspect ratio) control the sizing. However, the _Size_ has an influence. Let's say you create a cube with the mouse that has 1.5 meters, while the _Size_ is set to 2 meters. If you now change _Size_ to 4 meters, the actual cube dimensions will change to 3 meters, so the _Size_ value can be used as scaling factor.

Comment: NO WAY! Thanks everybody for this warm welcome (my 1st post), I really feel this as a group where we ca be related by this passion!

Comment: @thibsert and Gordon got it right! 
I absolutely didn't know about the "by-the-eye" measures set by dragging the mouse around... and I thought that when I entered the exact size by numbers, that would define the mesh... but that defines the scale so that mesh can become as wide as you want... 
a little akward, isn't? Especially because by the "Add" menu, the same action of manually entering a value just fixes the size... and not the scale!
THANKS!!